# Give Access to Freeform (Solspace) Submission Answers to a tierce person

Tags: plugin-freeform, authentication, bootstrap-craft

I implemented a form on a website using the Freeform Plugin (by Solspace) and I would like another company to have access to the results of this form.

I am thinking of using the bootstrap demo to display the submissions, but to access it one has to be connected to the Craft Account:

```
{% if currentUser and currentUser.admin %}
```

How can I create an authentication system but only for the Submission Page?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but thanks for making me learn a new word today! "tierce"